# Justification failure in beamer enumerate list

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I'm somewhat new to LaTeX and trying to make a presentation for my prelim exam...no big stress or anything. I'm using an overleaf template, and trying to use an enumerated list for a function with roman numerals. My problem is all items after the first are being left justified by a full tab space, not appearing directly beneath the (i) like it should...and in fact, the left justification takes it right over the margin of the page!  here's the things at the top for what packages are involved.

(Thanks for the editing help, and oops, first posted this as an answer to a related question. Deleted the answer form, ported to a new question)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}    
  \usecolortheme{default}

 \usefonttheme{default}  

  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

And my code

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\roman{enumi})}

\begin{enumerate}

    \item \phi(0,x)=x \forall x\in X


    \item \phi(t,\phi(s,x))=\phi(t+s,x), \forall s,t\inT^+,x\in X


\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: you have not posted a document that we can run to see the issue but `\item \phi(0,x)=x \forall x\in X` will clearly generate errors. you need to mark math mode in tex with (for example)  `\item $\phi(0,x)=x \forall x\in X$` _never_ ignore errors, after any error the pdf output is typically not usable, you should ask about the error message  rather than the output if you need help

Comment: Putting it in math mode fixed it, thanks!  And check, copy/paste more.  I didn't even notice the errors.  If you want to move that comment to an answer, I can accept it. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you don't need `\usecolortheme{default}

 \usefonttheme{default}`, as their name says, these are loaded by default

Comment: @samcarter Good to know.  The sample file I got had a bunch of commented out options to replace default with,  which is probably why the lines were there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have not posted a document that we can run to see the issue but

```
\item \phi(0,x)=x \forall x\in X
```

will clearly generate errors. you need to mark math mode in tex with (for example)

```
\item $\phi(0,x)=x \forall x\in X$
```

never ignore errors, after any error the pdf output is typically not usable, you should ask about the error message rather than the output if you need help